# show solutions of $y'' + p(t)y' + y = 0$ tend to 0

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to show that, if $p$ is a continuous periodic function (with period 1, but I don't think it matters), then all solutions to $y'' + p(t)y' + y = 0$ go to $0$ at $t=\infty$.

I can show that $y' \to 0$, but I'm not sure if this is helpful. I know that, in general, a vanishing derivative does not imply a convergent antiderivative, but I'm hoping that is the case in the context of this particular ODE.

Comment: Don't you need $p$ to be non-negative? If $p$ is, say, negative, I do not think this is true because you have an oscillating system with a friction term that would represent a force in the same direction of the velocity. Such a system would not stabilize,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\dfrac{d}{dt} (y'^2 + y^2) = 2 (y'' + y) y' = - 2 p(t) y'^2 $$

As GReyes commented, you want to assume $p(t) > 0$.

EDIT:  Since $p$ is periodic, this will imply $p(t) > \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon > 0$.    Then $E(t) = y'(t)^2 + y(t)^2$ is nonnegative and nonincreasing, so it has a limit $E_0$, and $y' \to 0$
(which is what you already proved).

But if $E_0 = 0$ that requires $y \to 0$ as well, while if $E_0 > 0$ you'd have $y \to y_0 = \pm \sqrt{E_0} \ne 0$.  But when $y' \approx 0$ and $y \approx y_0$, the differential equation says $y'' = -p(t) y' - y \approx - y_0$, so $y'$ could not stay near $0$.

Comment: I originally had the asymptotics argument you described, but I couldn't get over the fact that $y' \to 0$ doesn't necessarily imply $y \to c$ in the general case. But then you pointed out that $c$ exists because $E$ converges at infinity. Thank you!